# How to copy a directory from your home to a system wide one

Tags: sudo, folder, clipboard, gksu

I want to use the file manager to copy a directory from my Desktop to the `/opt` directory. When I run `gksudo nautilus`, I do not see anything in the Desktop directory.

If I open Nautilus normally from the taskbar, it shows the `lampp` directory along with other existing ones.

So how do I get to view this directory so I can cut and paste it into `/opt` directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing an empty desktop because it is root's desktop directory since you use gksudo to open Nautilus. So, when you open Nautilus just follow this path from the left sidebar:

> --> File system --> home --> your_user_name --> your_desktop

Then copy whatever you want. For an alternative way, you can use terminal for this:

```
sudo cp -r ~/Desktop/directory_that_will_be_copied /opt/where_to_copy
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run [Nautilus](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/nautilus.1.html) as [`root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) (with `gksu nautilus` or `gksudo nautilus`), it considers `root`'s [home directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) ([`/root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//root)) as the pertinent home directory, instead of your own home directory (`/home/shawn`, where **`shawn`** is replaced by your actual username, if different).

That sort of thing does not happen when you run nongraphical commands as root in [the usual way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) (i.e., with [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/sudo.8.html)). This is the main difference between the default behaviors of `sudo` and its graphical frontends like `gksu` and `gksudo`, and it is for [good reason](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo), since it is common for graphical programs to create and maintain configuration files in the home directory (which would either be rendered unchangeable by the non-`root` user and/or would provide a way for programs run as the non-`root` user to  create and modify configuration data altering the behavior of programs run as `root`, both of which would be undesirable).

As mentioned above, if your username is **`shawn`**, your home directory's full path is `/home/shawn`. Your desktop folder is then `/home/shawn/Desktop`. If you run Nautilus as `root` and navigate to that folder, you'll see (and be able to access and manipulate) the files on your desktop.